# I want to count all the rows for todays / yesterdays date based on a DATETIME - mysql+php

Tags: mysql, php, count

I have database "db2" with table "menjava"

In table menjava have "id", "author" and "date_submitted" field

- id - auto_increment
- author - int(11)
- date_submitted - datetime

I want to count all the rows for todays date and all the rows for yesterdays date (so there will be two codes with conditions) based on a DATETIME field called 'date_submitted' that holds the date and time of each record's creation.

In the file result.php, there is this count displayed, but it does not work. In the same file (result.php) I have some other code to display data from different database, so I think that povezava.php is working ok.

My code:

```
 <?
    require "povezava.php";
    $q=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number FROM menjava 
WHERE date_submitted >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)",$link2);
// now you can 
if ( $nt = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo $nt["total_number"];
$q=mysql_query($nt) or die(mysql_error());
}

    ?>
```

my file povezava.php looks like this:

```
<?
$servername='localhost';

$dbusername='user';
$dbpassword='pass';

$dbname1='db1';
$dbname2='db2';

$link1 = connecttodb($servername,$dbname1,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
$link2 = connecttodb($servername,$dbname2,$dbusername,$dbpassword);

function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword)
{
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword",TRUE);
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    return $link;
}
    ?>
```

Error that I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: NoticeMessage: Array to string conversionFilename: templates/master.phpLine Number: 231 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1
```

Fixed:

```
<?
    require "povezava.php";
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number FROM menjava WHERE date_submitted >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)",$link2);
// working 
if ( $nt = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo $nt["total_number"];
}

    ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access column by index :

```
if ( $nt = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo $nt[0];
}
```

(Note `if` instead of `while` - it's not required, but your query returns at most 1 row, so no need for `while`).
If you want to access column by name, change the query to use aliases:

```
$q=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number FROM menjava 
WHERE date_submitted >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)",$link2);
// now you can 
if ( $nt = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo $nt["total_number"];
}
```

Also, while debugging it makes sense to output errors if any :

```
$q=mysql_query(....) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I get this error: `Severity: WarningMessage: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean givenFilename: result.php`

Comment: So the query fails (the most likely because it shouldn't be a space between `COUNT` and `(*)` : `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`

Comment: ok..it is working.. I get count for today and yesterday but still  there is the same error: `Severity: WarningMessage: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, array givenFilename: result.phpLine Number: 231` how can I hide this or what can I do?

Comment: Can you post the code that produces error ? You pass array instead of string somewhere.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1

Comment: what exactly do you mean? which code?

Comment: i deleted `$q=mysql_query($nt) or die(mysql_error());` and it is working now...

Comment: Why did you add this line at all? :)